# How to execute the command zenity in a script executed by a service (systemd) (file .service)

Tags: linux, bash, service, systemd

I have a little problem. I am doing a service (daemon) with systemd. The script is the follow:

```
if [ $intento = 5 ];then
      iptables -I INPUT -s ${sublista[0]} -j DROP -m comment --comment "IP bloqueada por sshield"
      date=$(date)
      echo "${sublista[0]} $date" >> /var/cache/sshield.deny
      zenity --notification --text "IP address ${sublista[0]} denied at $date - sshield"
      email ivanherediaplanas@hotmail.com "Nueva regla iptables | ${sublista[0]} denied" "The ${sublista[0]} ip address is denied by brute force's attack ssh.<br><br>Date: $date"
      declare -a ips=(${ips[@]/${sublista[0]}=>$intento/})
fi
```

The idea is the follow:

> If the attempts is more than five, it give the ip address and lock it. Sending a mail and **showing a zenity's popup**

The problem is that, the popup doesn't show.

#### zenity --notification --text "IP address ${sublista[0]} denied at $date - sshield"

I believe that it is because, the scrpt is exeuted by a service's file in /lib/systemd/system/sshield.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Service for protect attacks of brute force ssh's

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/etc/sshield/sshield.sh
ExecStop=/etc/sshield/sshield.sh stop
RemainAfterExit=yes
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I believe that the problem is in: **Type=simple**

Also, I try with this:

```
  echo "${sublista[0]} $date" >> /var/cache/sshield.deny
  sshield --bell "IP address ${sublista[0]} denied at $date - sshield"
  email ivanherediaplanas@hotmail.com "Nueva regla iptables | ${sublista[0]} denied" "The ${sublista[0]} ip address is denied by brute force's attack ssh.<br><br>Date: $date"
```

> sshield --bell "IP address ${sublista[0]} denied at $date - sshield"

the command `sshield`, is a script in the path `/bin/sshield` and I get follow it:

```
elif [[ $argumento == "--bell" ]];then
    if [[ $# -gt 3 ]];then
            echo -e "\033[1;31m[-]\033[0m Only one value"
            echo "You use '--help' or '-h' for more information"
    elif [[ $# = 1 ]];then
            echo -e "\033[1;31m[-]\033[0m It needs one value"
            echo "You use '--help' or '-h' for more information"
    else
            zenity --notification --text "$2"
    fi
else
  [...]
```

mark: **zenity --notification --text "$2"**

But, it doesn't work. How to can I solve it?

The error is in zenity:
[image: journalctl -u sshield](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9Nhl.png)

Comment: Please examine the error log. It probably doesn't know which display to show up on since you run it outside of a UI.

Comment: What error log?

Comment: To view the log of a single systemd service, you can use `journalctl -u sshield`

Comment: What is the output of `zenity --notification --text "Whatever"` when you run it in a terminal?

Comment: The output `zenity --notification --text "whatever" show a popup with the text specified`. It work, but in a service not.

Comment: My **tty** is `tty7`. I run `zenity --notification --text "[...]" --display :7` and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For execute GUI (Graphics User Interface), in a service (systemd). First, you must add this:

```
[Service]
Environment="DISPLAY=:0"
Environment="XAUTHORITY=/home/ivan/.Xauthority"
```

Result:

```
[Unit]
Description=Service for protect attacks of brute force ssh's

[Service]
Type=simple
Environment="DISPLAY=:0"
Environment="XAUTHORITY=/home/ivan/.Xauthority"
ExecStart=/etc/sshield/sshield.sh
ExecStop=/etc/sshield/sshield.sh stop
RemainAfterExit=yes
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And in the script, add:

```
export DISPLAY=":0"
```

Comment: This should be marked as answer. It solves it. Thank you a lot! For my case I did not need to add `export DISPLAY=":0"` in the script. `Environment` variables did it for me, thanks!